# NAO Robotics student compile error: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

I am a teacher working with students on the NAO robot in Java.  We are using Eclipse.  This error pops up anytime a student attempts to compile their program:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\username\Desktop\jnaoqi-1.14-win32-vs2010\lib\jnaoqi.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

All of the reference library paths are correct.  The kicker is that I can log into the same exact system, map to the same exact libraries and compile without any issues.  It seems that there is a permissions in that my students can't access something that they need.

Does anyone has insight that might help me to track down the root of this issue?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://www.aldebaran-robotics.com/documentation/dev/java/troubleshooting.html?highlight=dll
Any luck with this?

Comment: Going off the error message alone. My guess is your machine is 32 Bit and/or using 32 bit Java, whilst the student's have their high tech 64 bit machines and 64-bit Java.

Comment: If you can log into the same computer and get everything to work then you probably have a different system path then your students.  Check if you have two versions of java installed (32 and 64 bit).  Your system path might have one or other listed first (opposite of your students) which causes it to be used during your compilation process successfully.

Comment: Thanks shandigraun, that link was very helpful.  Likewise, to everyone else, as that seemed to resolve the issue.  Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that the default java in your eclipse setup is 32-bit, while the students are getting a 64-bit version of java. Is suggest you check the preferences in eclipse and ensure you are all using the same architecture (i.e. 32-bit).

Answer (score 1):

From JNAOqi website:

> The native library has been compiled with the openjdk6, and should be
>   compatible with any later version of the JVM except on Windows where
>   **only the 32-bit version of Java is supported**.

So yeah, tell your students to get 32-bit version of jdk. It should work fine on 64-bit windows.

Answer (score 0):

You need both a Java 32-bit version and a Eclipse 32-bit version! I had this problem several times.
Also pay attention that if you want to run your program as a JAR file, you will need a .bat file that runs the JAR file by selecting the correct Java version. Alternatively just specify it when running it from the terminal.